# How to capture millisecond in arduino

Tags: arduino

It is possible to serial print how milliseconds every output high. Let say i write an code analogRead. If analogread bigger than 600, then digitalwrite 13, high. If output pin 13 high, then capture how millisecond until the pin 13 goto low.

I try millis() but it cannot reset back to zero... It there anyway to reset millis() to zero?

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable to keep track of your millis() count between events, kind of like a stop watch: you need to remember you started counting, so you can measure the difference when you stop.

Here's a quick sketch to illustrate the idea. Code isn't tested on an Arduino, but you should be able to understand the concept from the comments:

```
long lastTime;
int ledState = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int analogValue = analogRead(0);
  int newLedState = (analogValue > 600);//need to check, hoping boolean will evaluat to 1 when true

  if(ledState == 0 && newLedState == 1){//if the led was of, but will be turned on, start the stop watch
    lastTime = millis();//store the current time
    ledState = newLedState;
  }

  if(ledState == 1 && newLedState == 0){//if the led was on, but will be turned off, get the difference between the last time we started counting time
    long difference = millis() - lastTime; //get the current time, but subtract the last stored time
    ledState = newLedState;
    Serial.println(difference);
  }

  digitalWrite(13,ledState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think I understand what you want here. You want to capture the time difference between 2 pins changing their electrical state. To do this you can use `pulseIn()`.

Using your example in your question we get...

```
if (13 == HIGH) {
millis = pulseIn(13, LOW);
}
```

That will give you the duration between the pin going high and then going low, stored in the variable millis. It's good practice to store it in a long.